# Office 2013 ribbon plug-in for jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ribbon

Does anyone know a Office 2013 ribbon plug-in for jquery? I check this out but the source code seems to be removed from github: http://www.downscripts.com/jquery-ribbon_javascript-script.html

Comment: On a whim, I searched github for logic-software-solutions and found this repo, looks like someone managed to save a copy of it :) https://github.com/denniskroneb/jQuery.Ribbon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that it's some time ago already, but in fact, the ribbon was my creation, and I've deleted since I was not happy with it.

Maybe you are interested since I'm writing it again?

Anyway, here's the link: https://github.com/Kevin-De-Coninck/OfficeUI

Kind regards,

Kevin De Coninck

Comment: Sorry but I've renamed the project. It's here. https://github.com/Kevin-De-Coninck/OfficeWebControls however still a work in the progress.